# How to write a proper for loop for API calls?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that provides the author's short ID to a database called RePEc and gets the affiliation data. So far, this is what I have (NB: USERCODE only works on my IP):

```
url <- "https://api.repec.org/call.cgi?code=USERCODE&getauthorrecordraw="
for(i in 1:length(df_affiliations)){
Sys.sleep(1)
affiliation_fun <- paste(url,df_affiliations$author_reg_1[i])
affiliation_run <- fromJSON(txt=affiliation_fun) %>% select("affiliation") %>% unlist(use.names=FALSE)
affiliation_1 <- paste(unlist(affiliation_run), collapse =" ")
df_affiliations$vector <- rbind(affiliation_1)
}
```

Every time I try this, I either get only the last value or a HTTP Error 400. For loops are not my strong suit. Can anyone figure out where I've gone wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You probably want `paste0()` rather than `paste()`. The latter inserts a space which is probably bad from the URL. Also what is `class(df_affiliations$author_reg_1[i])`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. It's a character vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is over writing your output variable on each iteration.  A solution here is to initialize an empty vector outside of the loop and then assign the value to each index:

```
url <- "https://api.repec.org/call.cgi?code=USERCODE&getauthorrecordraw="

#define empty vector
affiliation_1<-vector(length=length(df_affiliations))
for(i in 1:length(df_affiliations)){
  Sys.sleep(1)
  affiliation_fun <- paste0(url,df_affiliations$author_reg_1[i])
  affiliation_run <- fromJSON(affiliation_fun) %>% select(affiliation) %>% unlist(use.names=FALSE)
  affiliation_1[i] <- paste(unlist(affiliation_run), collapse =" ")
}
```

This is untested since the question is not reproducible, but should provide a starting point for your final solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I know this isn't reproducible so it's possible you can't help but I keep getting this error: "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The column `affiliation` doesn't exist." However, if i do each of the individual steps without the for loop, the data comes out fine. If it helps, 'affiliation' is a dataframe listed inside the txt I'm getting. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: It could be possible that the call to `fromJSON` is not returning the expected results and thus causing the error.  I suggest restarting the R session to clear the environment to see if the problem is consistent.  Also maybe add a print statement to the loop to monitor which row is being processed at the time of the error.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dave2e - I will do that. Where would I add the print statement? At the end (i.e. 'print[i]')?

Comment: If you add it at start, then it will show the record which caused the error.  If you add it at the end then it will show the last successfully completed record.  Your preference.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your help. Small problem though - there are a few errors that I would like to just skip. Do you know how I can run this loop and just record 'error' or something like that if it doesn't work?

Comment: Take a look at the  `try` and `tryCatch` functions to test for an error and to properly handle it.